# services “kubernetes-dashboard” , can't access kubernetes ui

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

I am deploy kubernetes UI using this command:
kubectl apply -f kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.2.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
And it response "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 185.199.110.133:443: i/o timeout"

I behind proxy, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

All the services that you deployed via the supplied url don't have a kind specified. This means they will be using the default service type which is `ClusterIP`.

Services of Kind `ClusterIP` are only accessible from inside your Kubernetes Cluster.

If you want the Dashboard to be accessible from outside your Cluster, you will need a service of type `NodePort`. A NodePort Service will assign a random high number port on all your nodes on which your application, in this case the k8s dashboard, will be accessible via `${ip-of-any-node}:${assigned-nodeport}`.

For more information, please take a look at the official [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

If your cluster is behind a proxy, also make sure, that you can reach your clusters node's external ip from wherever you are trying to send the request from.

In order to find out what port number has been assigned to your NodePort service use `kubectl describe service ${servicename}` or `kubectl get service ${servicename} -o yaml`

Comment: thank you, but it mean i can't get it from the internet, can you check this link and tell me: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

Comment: you will need to eithr expose the dashboard via NodePort service, or setup an ingress controller exposed via nodeport service and then have a loadbalancer accessible from outside (i.e, the internet) to point to either your nodeport service or ingress controller. if you choose the ingress controller option you will also need to create an ingress pointing to your current dashboard service. 

the described way with kubectl proxy and accessing the dashboard via localhost does only work on the k8s nodes themselves. not from the public internet

Comment: check this part of the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui which reads "The UI can only be accessed from the machine where the command is executed. See kubectl proxy --help for more options."

Comment: i mean i can't get file recommanded.yaml from this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.2.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

Comment: no, you will not be able to access the dashboard from this yaml file without changes

Comment: when i use laptop in home no behind proxy i can do in command:" kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.2.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml", then command "kubectl proxy"-> then dashboard available at http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/.