# Deploying the Dashboard UI Error in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, proxy, dashboard

I deploy kubernetes UI using this command in windows 10:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.2.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml And it response "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 185.199.110.133:443: i/o timeout"

I behind proxy, i think need to config http proxy, how can i fix it?

Comment: Could you precise how did you set up your cluster? I don't quite understand how did you do it from windows? Can you clarify?

Comment: i get it from docker desktop

Comment: What is the difference between this and your second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68571539/services-kubernetes-dashboard-cant-access-kubernetes-ui? Note, that you should ask one time about one problem.

Comment: they are the same, i rewrite the question in details.

Comment: Please remove one of them and edit question if you want to add some new information.